# Fetching multipule endpoints at one return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { endpoint, apiKey } from "../api";
import Container from "../components/layouts/Container";

export default function Movie({ route }) {
  const { movieId } = route.params;
  const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const urls = [
    `${endpoint}/movie/${movieId}?api_key=${apiKey}`,
    `${endpoint}/movie/${movieId}/credits?api_key=${apiKey}`,
    `${endpoint}/movie/${movieId}/images?api_key=${apiKey}`,
    `${endpoint}/movie/${movieId}/reviews?api_key=${apiKey}`,
    `${endpoint}/movie/${movieId}/similar?api_key=${apiKey}`,
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      Promise.all(
        urls.map((url) => {
          return fetch(url);
        })
      )
        .then((response) => {
          return Promise.all(response.map((res) => res.json()));
        })
        .then((data) => {
          setMovieDetails(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(movieDetails[0]);
```

Hello,
I've encountered a problem tha that when i try to fetch the request above when i console.log() it it first returns undefined and then return the desired response.

Comment: This is how promises work. Kindly give them a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

The response is expected as initially the state is undefined.

During the request also, till the response is unresolved, the process is suspended and the state stays undefined.

A simple solve will be to move the `console.log(movieDetails[0])` into the last `.then()` body or you could write your own Promise resolution functions.

Comment: The thing is i'm trying to use the data fetched in this component in another component and it returns an error that that data is undefined

Comment: True, that is to be expected because a function returning a promise will return immediately, no matter if its a small process or a long drawn network call.

The promise can be resolved in the function which you are trying to implement, making its parameters as Promises. ATM, i dont see any other ideas how to resolve because you will encounter the undefined in any Promise right now.